# How to show the following gradient equation is true?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

Assuming that $\textbf{x}$ is a column vector($1\times n$) and $\textbf{B}$ is square matrix ($n\times n$) how can we show that the following property is true $$\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^T\textbf{Bx}}{\partial \textbf{x}}=(\textbf{B}+\textbf{B}^T)\textbf{x}$$

I tried to apply the product rule for differentiation (I am not sure whether it is applicable here or not, Please confirm) to get the following form $$\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^T\textbf{Bx}}{\partial \textbf{x}}=\textbf{Bx}+\textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}$$ which is not equal to the right side of my first equation. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x^TB=B^Tx$, you almost had it

Comment: @F.Conrad thank you for your comment but should there not be any condition that $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}$ should be symmetric?

Comment: Just do it in coordinates.

Comment: @F.Conrad and I think $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}$ can not be symmetric since its a row vector

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thank you for your comment. Do you think my application of product rule right or wrong? I did the following while applying the product rule $$\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}\textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}=\frac{\partial (\textbf{x}^T\textbf{B})}{\partial \textbf{x}}\textbf{x}+\textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}\frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}$$

Comment: Try the more general version: What is $\frac{\partial \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{z}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ in terms of $\mathbf{y}$, $\mathbf{z}$, $\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$, and $\frac{\partial\mathbf{z}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$?  To find out....use coordinates.  Vector derivatives are cool, but I think the very basic identities need to be worked out in their unabbreviated forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By components

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x_jB_{jk}x_k) &=& \frac{\partial x_j}{ \partial x_i}B_{jk}x_k +  x_j B_{jk}\frac{\partial x_k}{ \partial x_i}\\
&=& \delta_{ij}B_{jk}x_k + x_j B_{jk}\delta_{ki} \\
&=& B_{ik} x_k + x_j B_{ji} = ({\bf B} {\bf x})_i + ({\bf x^T}{\bf B})_i
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: thank you for your answer but I think (please correct me if I am wrong in this thinking) I also obtained the same answer in my second equation. From your answer we get that the $i$-th element of $\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}\textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}$ is the sum of the $i$-th elements of $\textbf{Bx}$ and $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}$ but (as represented by my first equation) it should be sum of $\textbf{Bx}$ and $\textbf{x}\textbf{B}^T$. Please add some more steps to make the equation look like same as my first equation. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I think there is no direct way of solving it in matrix and vector forms and we have to solve it in coordinates and since we want to represent the answer in the form of vector therefore in order to make addition valid we have to take the transpose of the second part in my second equation.

Comment: @FrankMoses The $i$-th component of term ${\bf x}^T {\bf B}$ is $x_j B_{ji}$, you can convince yourself of this by writing the vector and matrix explicitly and calculate the product for a couple of values of $i$

Comment: yes I understand it now. Thank you for your help.